# How can I iterate Url to capture all and subsequent files during file download

Tags: python, file

I am trying to download files from a directory, the only difference in the url of all the files is the date at the middle (https://eogdata.mines.edu/wwwdata/viirs_products/vnf/v30/VNF_j01_d20180607_noaa_v30-ez.csv.gz) I want to be able to increment and iterate the dates such that I will only supply one url that changes date. This is to avoid supplying over 500 urls to the codes. so far, I can only download one file.

```
import urllib.request
testfile = urllib.request.URLopener()
testfile.retrieve("https://eogdata.mines.edu/wwwdata/viirs_products/vnf/v30/VNF_j01_d20180607_noaa_v30-ez.csv.gz",
                  "C:/users/user 1/Desktop/20180607.gz")
```

Comment: Do you have a data range in mind? What is it?

Comment: Actually, because new files are added to the directory every 24 hours, I want to make it in such a way that it will take care of subsequent dates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's something that seems like a promising approach (I'm no expert). It uses the `re` regular expression module to parse the lines in a `request.urlopen()` response and looks for quoted filenames enclosed in double quotes that contain what looks like a date and end with the characters `'.gz'`:

```
import re
from urllib import request
from urllib.error import HTTPError

MAXLINES = 20  # To limit number of lines read - set to zero to disable.

directory = 'https://eogdata.mines.edu/wwwdata/viirs_products/vnf/v30'
pattern = re.compile(r""" "(\S*(\d{4} 0[1-9]|1[012] [012][0-9]|3[01])\S*\.gz)" """,
                     re.VERBOSE)
try:
    with request.urlopen(directory) as response:
        for i, line in enumerate(response, 1):
            match = pattern.search(line.decode('utf-8'))
            if match:
                print(match.group(1))  # Print matching filename.
            if MAXLINES and i > MAXLINES:  # Stop early? (for testing)
                break
except HTTPError as e:
    print('Failed to open directory')
    print('Reason: ', e.reason)
```

Comment: This worked for me, thanks @martineau. My I also ask why do you think the code below does not extract all the data that ends with .gz within the directory. I have tweaked it the much I can but obviously missing something

'directory = "https://eogdata.mines.edu/wwwdata/viirs_products/vnf/v30"'
testfile = urllib.request.urlopen(directory)
for line in testfile:  
    if line.endswith(b'gz'):
        urllib.request.retrieve(line)'

Comment: Mikko: Using `line.endswith(b'gz')` won't match the same lines as the regular expression in my answer does. I think you could do something like concatenate the `directory` + `'/'` + matching-filename strings together for use as the first argument in a separate `retrieve()` call. Something similar to that will also be needed to determine a local destination path of the downloaded file which is provided by the second argument in the same call to it.